# Flutter Navigator package with flexibility and simplicity

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm using Navigator 1.0 in flutter to handle different routes in the app. This is not enough to take care of all the scenarios in the app, either it's too complicated or a massive set of boilerplate code. I'm looking for a package which takes away all these pain points.

The basic idea is the library/code should be able to handle the following scenario at a minimum.

1. Navigation to another screen with the flexibility to send any kind of data as an argument.
2. The parent should be able to understand what happened with the child widget. e.g: Let's consider navigation happened from **A** -> **B**, then **B** should be also able to send data back to **A**. (So **A** can track the status of **B**)
3. Easier navigation should be there for Snackbar/Popup Dialog, and pop should be easy as well.
4. Parents should have the ability to wait for the completion of child widget. e.g: **A** opened one dialog **B**, **A** should have ability to wait for **B**'s completion.
5. The biggest pain point I'm facing is having difficulties with the nested Navigation system. e.g: **A -> B -> C -> D** navigation happens, And **A** needs to know what happened with **D**, in order to have this understanding, Data will be transferred from **D** to **C** to **B** to **A**. This becomes really difficult to manage if you have different nesting with different combinations(e.g: **ABCD**, **BCDA**, **CDAB**, **CDBA**).

Comment: all of your four points are supported by flutter's `Navigator` class, what kind of problems do you have with it?

Comment: I've added another 5th point which is really difficult to manage with Navigator.

Comment: it will work without any problems if you do `final result = await Navigator.push(ctx, ...); Navigator.pop(ctx, result);` in routes `B` and `C`

Comment: Sure we can do that, Let's consider if we have a long list of this navigation(a-b-c-d-e-f-g). This particular piece of code will be repeated. And It's a kind of cascading effect which is happening here. It will become more complicated if you'll try to maintain a different flow altogether.(a-c-b-d-e-g-f) Can't we have a way through which A can keep an eye on any child navigation page?

Comment: so pass to every route for example `ValueNotifier` or `Completer` or similar class and you will not have to pass the result in `pop` method - most likely `Completer` will be better here

Comment: Is it possible to keep track of any child widget, e.g Can b keep eye on e? Any code sample will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: just pass [Completer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) as a parameter and call `completer.complete` in the last route